# Does the Amazon Route 53 Resolver only work with AmazonProvidedDNS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-route53

I want to configure the Amazon Route 53 Resolver to forward queries for a subdomain to an on-prem DNS server in a on-prem network connected to my vpc via a VPN.

But I already have a dhcp scope configured on my vpc that points domain-name-servers to DNS servers I have running on ec2 instances in the VPC

I could configure the self hosted DNS servers running in the VPC to forward to the on-prem DNS servers, but wondering if this is also configurable with the Amazon Route 53 Resolver?

I assume its not because if my instances are pointing to my self hosted DNS servers in the VPC then how would the Amazon Route 53 Resolver have control over their DNS queries?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are correct, Route53 resolver service can only be used with AmazonProvidedDNS and the forward rules that are set up for a domai nto be forwarded to on-prem are only available at the resolver.

If you wish, you can set up forwarding rules for the specific subdomain to be routed to the AmazonProvidedDNS ( CIDR+ 2 address) ..

However, since you already have an EC2 acting like a DNS server, you may also configure the queries from VPC to be directly forwarded via this custom DNS server.

Resolver is also an expensive service so better to avoid it when posible